# Selecting all record in mysqli

Tags: select, mysqli

I want to select all record in mysqli, I am using the following syntax

$stmt->get_result();

but i am getting single data, i want to select all the data and then apply the while loop on the data.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a while loop:

```
$stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
  $rs[]=$row;
  //Or just process it here.
}
```

Or use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php